# I have a windows ssh host (freeSSHd). How do i get 256 colorschemes to work in vim when connecting through putty?

Tags: windows, ssh, vim, putty

What I'm trying to accomplish is to putty onto my windows host, and then use vim with full color functionality. How is that possible? I'm currently using freeSSHd but I'm willing to change to whatever to make this work.

Something else i noticed that might be related is that even tho putty is set to use utf-8, characters with acutes and such display incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to

```
export TERM=putty-256color
```

(specified via PuTTY Configuration > Connection > Data > Terminal-type string).

At least that works for me, connecting to Linux boxes as well as a local Cygwin OpenSSH server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but setting terminal-type string to xterm-256color or putty-256color does not work

Answer (score 0):

In putty by default it will using 256 colours mode, you can enable or disable it as well 
Check this under
 PuTTY Configuration > Windows > Colours >  Allow terminal to use xtem 256 colours  mode

Comment: Thanks but it does not work.